# Adding ng-click to div created with angular.element

Tags: angularjs

I have the following directive that has two children `div`s. The second div (created with `angular.element`) should be clickeable. Since I created it with `angular.element`, I'm trying to add `ng-click` with the `attr` function, but this doesn't work. What's wrong with this code?

```
       app.directive('mydir', function () {

                var directive = {};

                directive.restrict = 'EA';

                directive.replace = true;

                directive.scope = {
                     control: '=',
                };

                directive.template = '<div id="root"></div>';

                directive.link = function (scope, element, attrs) {

                        var wrap = angular.element('<div id="wrap"></div>');
                        element.append(wrap);                               
                        var node = angular.element('<div id="node"></div>');
                        node.attr('ng-click', 'toggle()');   // <--- this doesn't work
                        wrap.append(node);

                        scope.toggle = function () {
                            alert('clicked');
                        };
                });

                return directive;

            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element has to be compiled using angular's `$compile` service:

```
       app.directive('mydir', function ($compile) { // added dependency here

                var directive = {};

                directive.restrict = 'EA';

                directive.replace = true;

                directive.scope = {
                     control: '=',
                };

                directive.template = '<div id="root"></div>';

                directive.link = function (scope, element, attrs) {

                        var wrap = angular.element('<div id="wrap"></div>');
                        element.append(wrap);                               
                        var node = angular.element('<div id="node"></div>');
                        node.attr('ng-click', 'toggle()');   // <--- this doesn't work
                        var content = $compile(node)(scope);
                        wrap.append(content);

                        scope.toggle = function () {
                            alert('clicked');
                        };
                });

                return directive;

            });
```

[Here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/07/using-compile-in-angular.aspx)'s a short tutorial on using `$compile`. Hope that helps

Comment: I'm getting `Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'` when it tries to append the `content`

Comment: Oops.. it should actually be `var content = $compile(node)(scope);`.. ill update the answer...

Comment: thanks, it works. I created this plunk with the answer http://plnkr.co/edit/6jIQm5WgElAnD6ZGQ4mp?p=preview